# Save image projections on the same object in the same 'static' texture

Tags: texturing, uv, project

I have a scene with a big mesh and a small camera that I use to project an image on it (using the UV project modifier). I want to project this image on the object for different positions and orientations of the camera/projector and save all the projections in a permanent texture of the object. Is there a simple way to do it? (I'm using Blender 2.9)

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you're trying to do, if you're trying to project a texture on the surface of your object, maybe try the Stencil option of the Draw brush?

Comment: Do you mean you want to combine the projections into one image texture?

Comment: @Robin Betts yes indeed. I'm projecting the same image with the same camera, therefore ideally the texture would update regularly with the new projections

Comment: @moonboots I'm projecting an image on an object already, and I want the object's texture to "memorize it" and do this with other future projections of the same image with the same camera